How to Use GridView in a SingleChildScrollView
I am creating a dashboard for my project where I need to display a grid of buttons. I am utilizing GridView for this purpose, but it's causing issues when used with SingleChildScrollView.
Here is the code:
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:forest_fire/gridcard.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          top: true,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8, 0, 8, 0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: textEditingController,
                      focusNode: focusNode,
                      autofocus: true,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Services",
                          labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium?.copyWith(
                            fontFamily: 'Plus Jakarta Sans',
                            color: Color(0xFFA5A5A5),
                            letterSpacing: 0.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                          hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium?.copyWith(
                            fontFamily: 'Readex Pro',
                            letterSpacing: 0.0,
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xFF696969),
                                width: 2.0,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
                                  width: 2.0
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)
                          ),
                          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
                                  width: 2.0
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)
                          ),
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.search
                          ),
                          suffixIcon: Icon(
                              Icons.mic_none
                          )
                      ),
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(
                        fontFamily: 'Readex Pro',
                        letterSpacing: 0.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/download_1.png',
                            width: 360,
                            height: 160,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(-1, 0),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(16, 16, 0, 0),
                      child: Text(
                        'POPULAR SERVICES',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall?.copyWith(
                          fontFamily: 'Readex Pro',
                          letterSpacing: 0.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 300,
                      child: GridView(
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                            childAspectRatio: 1
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        children: [
                          GridCard(iconData: Icons.fire_truck_outlined, text: "Fire Stations"),
                          GridCard(iconData: Icons.restore_sharp, text: "Logo"),
                          GridCard(iconData: Icons.content_paste_outlined, text: "FWI"),
                          GridCard(iconData: Icons.location_on_outlined, text: "Location Tracker"),
                          GridCard(iconData: Icons.keyboard_control_sharp, text: "More",),
                        ],
                      )
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(-1.0, 0.0),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                      const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(16.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'SERVICE CATEGORIES',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall?.copyWith(
                          fontFamily: 'Readex Pro',
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                          letterSpacing: 0.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/video_1.png',
                        width: 347.0,
                        height: 68.0,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/video_1.png',
                        width: 347.0,
                        height: 68.0,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/video_1.png',
                        width: 347.0,
                        height: 68.0,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

Note: I do not want my GridView to be scrollable. Instead, I want my Column to be scrollable and my GridView to be large enough to display all my gridCards.

My suggestion is use customscrollview and silvergrid.Using shrinkWrap in gridview with singlechildscrollview will work but it is not optimal solution and cause unexpected lagging if the layout is complex.

Your code will work, but Just remove the Flexible Widget from the scroll view:
result:


Please try this code to use gridView in a singleChild Scroll view.
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Other widgets can go here before the GridView
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true, // Important for SingleChildScrollView
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Disable GridView scrolling
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            children: List.generate(20, (index) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Item $index',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          // Other widgets can go here after the GridView
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),

